# Is there a word for large group of horses?

Tags: vocabulary, collocations, collective-nouns

Is there a word for large group of horses? I know there's "flock" for birds, but I am wondering if there's a similar word for horses and land mammals.

Comment: Closed before I could answer. There is a particular use of **stable** which means a *group* of horses. Although it usually means a *place* where a horse is kept, it goes further, as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stable) says: **stable² 1.2** The racehorses of a particular training establishment. *A memorial service is planned for Lyon next July at Monmouth, where he trained a small stable.*

Answer (score 3):

The word you want is [**herd**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herd):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : a typically large group of animals of one kind kept together under human control
>         // a *herd* of cattle
>   **1 b** : a congregation of gregarious wild animals
>         // *herds* of antelopes

So:

> I see a flock of birds and a *herd* of horses.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jason Bassford's excellent answer, you could also say:

> **1. Troop:** A group of people or animals of a particular kind.

— [**Lexico**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/troop)

Example: A troop of horses.

---

> **2. Stud:** A collection of horses or other domesticated animals belonging to one person.
>
> Example: He kept a large stud of racehorses.

A stud of horses implies that the horses are kept specifically for breeding. You can't use stud in general sense.

— **[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stud)**

Comment: "stud" imples that the horses are kept specifically for breeding.

Comment: @JamesK, Indeed, but without further context, all the options are equally acceptable.

Comment: I think it is worth you including that in your answer.  You can't use "a stud of horses" in general sense, It implies more than just "a group".